# Firestore "where" query not working as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do a simple query from my firestore data base but I am missing something very obvious. I tried looking online but nothing works. For some background, I have a "cf" collection where I am trying to query a the objects that have the "hsc" value equal to "1" but I don't get anything in return.

[image]

```
exports.getOneTodo = (request, response) => {
    db
        .collection('cf')
        .where("hsc", "==", "1") 
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {

            if (!doc.exists) {
                return response.status(404).json(
                    { 
                        error: 'Todo not found' 
                    });
            }
            TodoData = doc.data();
            TodoData.todoId = doc.id;
            return response.json(TodoData);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return response.status(500).json({ error: error.code });
        });
};
```

[image]
Below are the firestore rules.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write
    }
  }
}
```

I am testing this via the postman. I have tried changing the firebase rules to be true for anything but still, nothing seems to be working.

UPDATE:
The following is how I initialized my DB

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = { admin, db };
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of code and text.  Copy the code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Sorry, just changed it.

Comment: Please change your security rules as well.

Comment: Just changed them too :)

Comment: If you hardcode the `"1"` string in the query, do you still get no results?

Comment: I tried hardcoding it and I still get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is expecting a single document, but it has to be prepared for the query to return multiple documents.  When you run `get()` on a Query object, it's going to yield a [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) object.   As you can see from the API documentation, it doesn't have an `exists` property.  A check for that property will always be "false".  What you have to do instead is check the results to first see if there were any documents, then get the first one:

```
    db
        .collection('cf')
        .where("hsc", "==", "1") 
        .get()
        .then((qsnapshot) => {
            if (qsnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                const dsnapshot = qsnapshot.docs[0];
                // send the response using dsnapshot.data()
            }
            else {
                // send the response saying nothing was found
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

now you need to use

```
  db.collection("id").whereGreaterThan("field","value")
  .whereEqualTo("field","value")
  .whereLessThen("field","value")
```